# Singleton in multi threaded environment

Tags: multithreading, logging, design-patterns, singleton

I Have a Singleton class called `FILELOGGER` and property called number_of_lines. 
I will make sure only one object is able to create for `FILELOGGER` class which makes singleton.

Throughout my application, my object is able to write it to a file and update `number_of_lines` property for each write.

What if i use this design pattern in multi threaded environment. How it behaves and i feel like `number_of_lines` property should be locked when other threads are trying to update. And I might to loose logging of data with delay and performance will be loosing.

Say for example thread `T1` is logging at time 10:10:10 and `T2` is also logging at the same exact time and both trying to update `number_of_lines` property.

How to solve this problem? Is there any alternative design pattern to solve this. Thanks for your time.

Comment: " how it behaves and i feel like number_of_lines property should be locked when other threads are trying to update. and i might to loose logging of data with delay and performance will be loosing." not sure what you mean here yet. But I think you have to lock both the `writeToFile` function (or your file will be messed up) and the field `number_of_lines` to make value atomic.

Comment: yes. if i lock both writeToFile and field number_of_lines . i will end with loosing performance as other write operations will be waiting in queue and will not able to log at exact time

Comment: OK I will give you 2 solution: 1. include the time in message. 2. Write to multiple file. (losing not loosing btw)

Comment: i think its a bad approach to write to multiple files for each thread associated and then run a algorithm to merge these files . messy would it be. isn't it.

Comment: What do you exactly want: Keep thevariables in a consistent state? Be able to determine which event happened before the other? Mitigate performance bottlenecks?

Comment: What is the environment you work in: winapi? .net? python? c++ 11?

Comment: Then custom the class FILELOGGER, and setting property `time` at the time it is about to log instead of taking the current sys time.

Answer (score 0):

You can either synchronize access to the whole file as you've already done, or there's an alternative with some *cons*: *snapshotting*.

- *N* threads write file contents to a `string` variable.
- A dedicated thread does snapshots of in-memory data to disk and updates `number_of_lines`. `number_of_lines` will be synchronized when this dedicated thread needs to update it. Snapshotting may occur in time intervals like 10 seconds, 1 minute, 1 hour...

The main issue with this approach is an application/system crash will mean losing the data that wasn't persisted to disk since the last snapshot, but since your application works with in-memory data, it should increase overall performance.

Answer (score 0):

Also you have to implement the singleton pattern in a thread safe way. I think the best approach is with an inner class to guarantee the purpose of the singleton in a multi threaded application.